# Creating cephfs volume in a test environment is very slow

Tags: filesystems, ceph

I've installed Ceph into a single VM for testing purposes (I'm not testing ceph, per se, but I need a ceph endpoint for the tools I'll be running). The install was easy enough, but the cephfs filesystem I've tried to create (`ceph fs volume create tank`) is taking forever (where "forever" means "at least 20 minutes so far") to become available.  Running `ceph mds status` shows:

```
tank:1 {0=tank.ceph.znlhma=up:creating} 1 up:standby
```

Running `ceph status` shows:

```
  cluster:
    id:     0350c95c-e59a-11eb-be4b-52540085de8c
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            1 MDSs report slow metadata IOs
            Reduced data availability: 64 pgs inactive
            Degraded data redundancy: 64 pgs undersized
            OSD count 1 < osd_pool_default_size 3

  services:
    mon: 1 daemons, quorum ceph.storage (age 50m)
    mgr: ceph.storage.pealqx(active, since 50m)
    mds: 1/1 daemons up, 1 standby
    osd: 1 osds: 1 up (since 50m), 1 in (since 58m)

  data:
    volumes: 1/1 healthy
    pools:   2 pools, 64 pgs
    objects: 0 objects, 0 B
    usage:   6.1 MiB used, 100 GiB / 100 GiB avail
    pgs:     100.000% pgs not active
             64 undersized+peered
```

That's mostly expected, except for the "1 MDSs report slow metadata
IOs", which I guess is symptomatic. There is a single OSD, on a 100GB
virtual disk (`/dev/vdb`), which is backed by a btrfs filesystem on an
NVME disk.

Is there anything I can do to make this faster to create? I don't need
Ceph to be particularly performant, but I would like to be able to
bring this test environment up in less time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that ceph, by default, won't activate an OSD with fewer than three replicas. The solution is to set the `min_size` for the corresponding pool, like this:

```
ceph osd pool set cephfs.tank.meta min_size 1
ceph osd pool set cephfs.tank.data min_size 1
```

(Replacing `cephfs.tank.meta` and `cephfs.tank.data` with whatever pool names are appropriate in your environment.)